# how to time this execution?

Tags: java, timer

I am trying to time the execution this loop but when i compile it runs fine, i just get an output of "Total execution time: 0"

```
package Time;

public class Time {

public Time() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int n = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
          for (int j = 1; j <= 1000; j++)
              sum = sum + j;
    }
    final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) );
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it execute too fast, you can check with `nanoTime` instead :

```
final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
final long endTime = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the amount in the loop.

Or do a heavier mathematical equation.

Also, use [System.nanoTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) for nano timings.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // 1 second = 0.000000001 nanoseconds

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    int n = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 1_000_000_000; j++)
            sum = sum + j;
    }

    System.out.printf("Total execution time: %07.3f secs", 

        (System.nanoTime() - startTime) * 1e-9);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all `n` is zero, making the outer `for` loop practical useless (it will only be entered once). Second:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 1000; j++)
```

make a `1000000` out of the `1000`. Maybe you will get some results then. The current execution is simply too fast for sensible time measurements.